# Difference between W_T*X of Logistic regression and Linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

We used W<sup>T</sup>*X to calculate the distance of a point in logistic regression from the equation of a hyperplane to the point and then tried to minimize the distance but in linear regression, we are taking W<sup>T</sup>*X as the equation of a line and then take its y<sup>^</sup> (i.e y_predicted value) by putting the X value in the equation of the line. So my question is that how is W<sup>T</sup>*X different in both logistic and linear regression?